# How to apply conditional formatting to multiple checkboxes?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, xml

For each entry there are about 20 checkboxes ( yes or no ) across. 
How do I apply conditional formatting to set a style depending on whether the value is yes or no across multiple checkboxes?

At the moment I would have to apply conditional formatting twice for each checkbox depending if the value is yes or no. Is there a way to do this in a less arduous and more practical way?
[image]

Under "Advanced Condition" , the XPath expression for above is:
    $thisNode/@A_x002d_01.value = '1'

Perhaps there is a generic statement I can use that refers to any field value as opposed to just "A-01"? Then apply them to each and every checkbox

I tried:
$thisNode.value = '1'
and it errored out. Apologies I am a novice at best at the above.